# Writing a python script to scrape excel data and write to a CSV, how do I get the proper output?

Tags: python, excel, csv, parsing

I've got an Excel document with rows named 'foo' and and columns named 'bar'. Foo and bar are sometimes associated with an 'x'.

[FooBar Tracker Excel Doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4nA2.png)

I've written some python code that searches the document for 'x' and then lists the associated foo and bar values. When I just print the output, all of the values are printed to the console. When I try to store the output as a variable and print the variable, I only get the final valid foo and bar combination.

```
import xlrd
import csv

###Grab the data 
def get_row_values(workSheet, row):
    to_return = []
    num_cells = myWorksheet.ncols - 1
    curr_cell = -1
    while curr_cell < num_cells:
        curr_cell += 1
        cell_value = myWorksheet.cell_value(row, curr_cell)
        to_return.append(cell_value)
    return to_return

file_path = 'map_test.xlsx'

myWorkbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_path)
myWorksheet = myWorkbook.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
num_rows = myWorksheet.nrows - 1
curr_row = 0
column_names = get_row_values(myWorksheet, curr_row)
print len(column_names)
while curr_row < num_rows:
        curr_row += 1 
        row = myWorksheet.row(curr_row)
        this_row = get_row_values(myWorksheet, curr_row)
        x = 0
        while x <len(this_row):
            if this_row[x] == 'x':
                    #print this_row[0], column_names[x]  
### print this_row[0], column_names[x] works 
### when I un-comment it, and prints foo and bar associated in the 
### proper order
                    output = "[%s %s]" % (this_row[0], column_names[x]) 
            x += 1

print output 
###Using the output variable just outputs the last valid foo/bar 
###combination
```

Why is this? How do I fix it?

Second, when I try to write the data to a .csv file, the broken output gets added to the .csv with one character in each cell. I need to be able to have each unique value go into its own cell, and control which cells they go into. Here's what I have so far:

```
myData = [["number", "name", "version", "bar" "foo"]]

myFile = open('test123.csv', 'w')
with myFile:
        writer = csv.writer(myFile)
        writer.writerows(myData)
        writer.writerows(output) ###This just outputs the last valid foo 
###and bar combination
print ("CSV Written")
```

The output ends up looking like this: 
[Results I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvGQl.png)

But I want it to look like this: 
[Results I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H41XL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `output` variable (your accumulator) is not continually adding values but over-writing the row, column values every loop run. Your `print` statement works because it is printing for every loop run and that's what you see.

To fix, set your output variable as an empty list outside of your while loops:

```
output = []
```

Then change this line:

```
output = "[%s %s]" % (this_row[0], column_names[x])
```

To this:

```
output.append([this_row[0], column_names[x]])
```

The other problem you are having is that your output was coming out funny. This is because of this line:

```
output = "[%s %s]" % (this_row[0], column_names[x])
```

You are asking python to render `this_row` as a string and then give you the character in position `[0]`, which is likely just "f". The above change to your code fixes this also.

On a side note, it would be considered better form to use a `for` loop for this instead of a `while` loop. e.g.

```
for row in range(0,num_rows) :
```

Comment: It turns out that I was able to fix my first problem by simply putting the print output command in my loop. I'll check to see if this resolves my second problem and update.  Thank you!

Comment: Understood. I took the time out to write this correct answer. Please award it as such.

Comment: That did the trick, now how do I bump the output of foo and bar over to different columns?

Comment: csvwriter doesn't "address" columns explicitly, so if you need to shuffle things over, you need to literally put blank spaces into your list. I assume that you also need to switch the orders of your bars and foos. Use a list comprehension like this one to automatically add the spaces and switch the order. 
Assuming this is what you have:
`output_sample = [["foo1", "bar2"], ["foo1", "bar3"], ["foo2", "bar1"]]`
Do this...
`rearranged_output = [["","","", foobars[1], foobars[0]] for foobars in output_sample]`
To get this:
`[['', '', '', 'bar2', 'foo1'], ['','','','bar3','foo1'],...`

Comment: Also, change your `open` line to this to deal with the extra white spaces: `myFile = open('test.csv', 'w', newline = "")`